# Banco de dados para de funcionar após algumas horas

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Olá, nesse sistema de cadastro, pego as informações inseridas e jogo em um banco de dados.

```
    include("connection.php");
require("blowfish.php");

$login = $_POST['login_cadastro'];
$senha = $_POST['senha_cadastro'];
$confirmarsenha = $_POST['confirmarsenha_cadastro'];
$email = $_POST['email_cadastro'];

if($senha != $confirmarsenha)
{   
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
          <script type='text/javascript'>alert('As senhas estão diferentes')</script>";
}
else
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'MINHASENHA', '');
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = ? OR email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $login, $email);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpegar))
    {   
        $login_db = $linha['login'];
        $email_db = $linha['email'];
    }

    if($login_db == $login)
    {
        echo "  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>
                <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse usuario já existe')</script>";
    }
    if($email_db == $email)
    {
        echo "  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>
                <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse email já esta sendo usado')</script>";
    }
    else
    {   
        $senha = hash_password($senha);
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'MINHASENHA', '');
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(login, senha, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $login, $senha, $email);
        $stmt->execute();

        header("location: index.php");  
    }
}
mysqli_close($coneccao);
return false;
```

E como pode-se ver eu não permito emails ou logins iguais.

Após fazer o cadastro o login do mesmo funciona perfeitamente.

```
<?
include "connection.php";
require "blowfish.php";

$login = $_POST['login_entrar'];
$senha = $_POST['senha_entrar'];

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'MINHASENHA', '');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $login);
$stmt->execute();

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $senha_db = $linha['senha'];
    $login_db = $linha['login'];
}

$cont = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if($login_db != $login || $login == "")
{       
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Este usuario não existe')</script>";      
}
else
{
    if(verifica_hash($senha, $senha_db))
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login_usuario'] = $login;

        header("location: index.php");         
    }
    else{   
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
            <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Senha incorreta')</script>";  
    }
}
mysqli_close($coneccao);
```

?>

porem após algumas horas se eu tentar fazer login ele informa que o usuário não existe, porem no banco de dados o usuário esta lá e eu posso criar uma nova conta com o mesmo nome que criei a algumas horas.

[image]

Obs:O site esta hospedado em um VPS.

Comment: Tente definir um index `UNIQUE` na sua coluna de login, apenas para teste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua lógica está errada.

```
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpegar))
{   
    $login_db = $linha['login'];
    $email_db = $linha['email'];
}
```

nesse trecho você acaba ficando somente com os dados do ultimo registro, logo somente a ultima pessoa cadastrada consegue logar e na checagem pela existência a comparação também só acontece com o ultimo nome de usuário cadastrado.

Bom depois da atualização da pergunta e discussão o código final deve ficar semelhante a isso.

```
include("connection.php");
require("blowfish.php");

$login = $_POST['login_cadastro'];
$senha = $_POST['senha_cadastro'];
$confirmarsenha = $_POST['confirmarsenha_cadastro'];
$email = $_POST['email_cadastro'];

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'MINHASENHA', '');

if($senha != $confirmarsenha)
{   
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
          <script type='text/javascript'>alert('As senhas estão diferentes')</script>";
}
else
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT login, email FROM usuarios WHERE login = ? OR email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $login, $email);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($login_db, $email_db);
    if($stmt->fetch())
    {   
        if($login_db == $login)
        {
            echo "  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse usuario já existe')</script>";
        }
        else if($email_db == $email)
        {
            echo "  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse email já esta sendo usado')</script>";
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        $senha = hash_password($senha);
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(login, senha, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $login, $senha, $email);
        $stmt->execute();

        header("location: index.php");  
    }
}

return false;
```

e

```
include "connection.php";
require "blowfish.php";

$login = $_POST['login_entrar'];
$senha = $_POST['senha_entrar'];

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'MINHASENHA', '');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT login, senha FROM usuarios WHERE login = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $login);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $login_db, $senha_db);
if($stmt->fetch())
{
    if($login == "")
    {       
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Este usuario não informado')</script>";      
    }
    else
    {
        if(verifica_hash($senha, $senha_db))
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login_usuario'] = $login;

            header("location: index.php");         
        }
        else
        {   
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
                <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Senha incorreta')</script>";  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E como devo fazer para pegar o banco de dados inteiro ??

Comment: Bom, normalmente você colocaria a busca/comparação direto na consulta, vou atualizar a resposta em breve com um exemplo que poderia solucionar seu problema.

Comment: Sim, eu fazia isso antes,  porem pensava que era desnecessário e retirei, mas acabei de colocar de novo.

Comment: Da forma que está na pergunta todos os usuários seriam retornados e você teria que comparar um a um no código para saber se existe alguém utilizando aquele login ou email.

Comment: Se for realizar a comparação na consulta se lembre de tratar os dados para evitar SQL Injection.

Comment: Olá, eu atualizei meu código, coloquei a verificação para pegar o usuário certo, porem continua dando o mesmo problema, vou atualizar minha pergunta.

Comment: você atualizou a forma da consulta, porem o while ficou errado, se quiser continuar no bate-papo só iniciar ele.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23853/discussion-between-lucas-carezia-and-hwapx).

Comment: @HwapX podes atualizar a resposta com as conclusões do chat? assim a resposta fica completa. `+1`